# Why RailsAdmin is so slow to load my edit view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I'm building an admin interface to my Rails website with the gem rails_admin. My problem is that when I try to edit a `FirstJob` model, the view takes about 15+ seconds to load.

After some testing, it seems that the field that causes this huge load time is `study_domains` because when I remove it from the edit action the load time decrease drastically to a second or so.

To give a little bit of context, in my app I have multiple jobs and each job can have multiple study domains through a table called `skilltags` that is a bridge between different `study_domain` and `field_of_study` to different objects, here's the association:

**first_job.rb, internship.rb & student_job.rb**

```
belongs_to :company
belongs_to :company_logo, class_name: "Document", optional: true

has_many :skilltags, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :hard_skills, :through => :skilltags
has_many :study_domains, -> { distinct }, :through => :skilltags
has_many :field_of_studies, :through => :skilltags
has_many :favourites, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :candidacies
has_many :users_candidacy, class_name: 'User', :through => :candidacies, source: :user
has_many :users_favourite, class_name: 'User', :through => :favourites, source: :user
has_many :documents, :dependent => :destroy
has_one :address, :dependent => :destroy
```

**company.rb**

```
has_many :first_jobs, -> {where(deleted: false)}
has_many :internships, -> {where(deleted: false)}
has_many :student_jobs, -> {where(deleted: false)}
has_many :alerts
has_many :documents, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :articles
has_many :testimonies
has_one :profile
has_one :user, :through => :profile
has_one :address

has_many :companies, class_name: "Company", foreign_key: "parent_id"
belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Company", optional: true

belongs_to :logo, class_name: "Document", optional: true
belongs_to :main_image, class_name: "Document", optional: true
belongs_to :banner_image, class_name: "Document", optional: true

serialize :list_videos, Array
serialize :featured_characteristics, Array
serialize :featured_pictures, Array
```

**skilltag.rb**

```
belongs_to :user, optional: true
belongs_to :soft_skill, optional: true
belongs_to :hard_skill, optional: true
belongs_to :first_job, optional: true
belongs_to :internship, optional: true
belongs_to :student_job, optional: true
belongs_to :study_domain, optional: true
belongs_to :field_of_study, optional: true
```

**study_domain.rb**

```
has_many :field_of_studies
has_many :skilltags, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :first_jobs, through: :skilltags
has_many :internships, through: :skilltags
```

**soft_skill.rb**

```
has_one :skilltag
```

**hard_skill.rb**

```
has_many :skilltags
has_many :users, :through => :skilltags
has_many :first_jobs, :through => :skilltags
```

**field_of_study.rb**

```
has_many :experiences
belongs_to :study_domain, optional: true
has_many :skilltags
has_many :first_jobs, :through => :skilltags
has_many :internships, :through => :skilltags
```

**experience.rb**

```
belongs_to :school, optional: true
belongs_to :campus, optional: true
belongs_to :field_of_study, optional: true
has_many :experience_tags, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :years, through: :experience_tags
```

**rails_admin.rb**

```
edit do
    field :company do
        inline_add false
    end
    field :title
    field :start_date
    field :description, :ck_editor
    field :active
    field :approved
    field :active_until
    field :searched_profile, :ck_editor
    field :specialization
    field :we_offer, :ck_editor
    field :motivation_letter
    field :application_email
    field :company_name
    field :company_size, :enum do
        enum do
            ApplicationController.helpers.company_size_collection.map { |size|
                [size[:en], size[:name]]
            }
        end
    end
    field :company_description, :ck_editor
    field :application_url, :string
    field :company_logo
    field :video_url
    field :study_domains do
        inline_add false
    end
    field :field_of_studies do
        inline_add false
    end
    field :users_candidacy do
        inline_add false
    end
    field :address
    field :sector, :enum do
        enum do
            ApplicationController.helpers.sector_collection.map { |sector|
                [sector[:en], sector[:name]]
            }
        end
    end
    field :department, :enum do
        enum do
            ApplicationController.helpers.department_collection.map { |department|
                [department[:en], department[:name]]
            }
        end
    end
    field :contract_type, :enum do
        enum do
            ApplicationController.helpers.contract_type_collection.map { |contract_type|
                [contract_type[:en], contract_type[:name]]
            }
        end
    end
    field :regime, :enum do
        enum do
            ApplicationController.helpers.regime_collection.map { |regime|
                [regime[:en], regime[:name]]
            }
        end
    end
    field :study_level, :enum do
        enum do
            ApplicationController.helpers.study_level_collection.map { |study_level|
                [study_level[:en], study_level[:name]]
            }
        end
    end
    field :language, :enum do
        enum do
            ApplicationController.helpers.primary_language_collection.map { |language|
                [language[:en], language[:value]]
            }
        end
    end
end
```

I don't know if there is enough details here but if you have any question I'll update my question with some more informations.

Comment: The SQL output looks too small, try setting the log level to debug to see ALL queries.

Comment: @GuillermoSiliceoTrueba Thanks for your comment, I added all the logs

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the output the main problem seems to be the internships i takes almost 9 seconds to execute the SQL and i bet that the rendering time is half your view.
Could you update your question with the rest of the associations involded in this view? internships, first_jobs, experiences, skilltags.

Rails admin is supposed to limit the number of records on those form_filtering_multiselects but it does not seem to be doing it.

Also you might want to explore the possibility of splitting this view into multiple tabs adding new custom rails admin actions.

UPDATE

I added the logs you posted earlier to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/grillermo/e61347466b4b923e6f08d04a453c535c) as reference.

From the logs the most expensive queries are those to get internships but you say that you are editing the first_job model and in that model there's no internships associations.
Thanks for being so cooperative, but if you could also post the rails_admin for the FirstJob model, because i can't understand why and how are those internships being loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately I maxed out the character limit for my question. But to give you a little more details, we have `companies` that gets multiple `first_jobs`,  `internships` and `student_jobs`. Each jobs can be linked to `soft_skills`, `hard_skills`, `field_of_studies` and `study_domains` via a skilltag that is a bridge between these ids. In this example I'm trying to edit a `first_job`, are these internships loaded because of the `companies` / `ìnternships` association?

Comment: I would think so. But you can remove the logs to post all the associations i just want to be completely sure of how do they look to suggest how to separate their edition in different views or a possible optimization

Comment: I edited my question, let me know if there is a missing association that you would need

Comment: I think that internships are loaded because of the `has_many :internships, through: :skilltags` on `study_domain.rb`. When Rails Admin load all the study_domains so I can add and remove some to my first_job, it also load all the internships associated to a study_domain, am I possibly right?

Comment: You might be on track, but it should not need to load ALL the StudyDomain associations to display them on the FirstJob edit, unless you the displayed name of a study_domain depends on the internships. Also it could be that study_domains are being displayed as a nested form, this happens with accept_nested_attributes.